# Alternative way for setting default for @Value-annotated field in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-annotations

I have a Spring Boot application written in Kotlin and I would prefer to set the default of a @Value-annotated field like below:

```
@Value("\${service-clients.logging.exceptions:/}")
private var loggingExceptions: Array<String> = emptyArray()
```

Is there anything wrong with doing it this way? Most of the resources I found on the web recommend to set the default in the annotation itself. Is there any advantage of doing it that way?

Comment: I would expect that this wouldn't even work, and lead to a `null` being set instead or whatever the default would be. But here my lack of knowledge of Kotlin might show :).

Comment: Do you meant that if the code was in Java, then it would lead to a null being set?

Comment: Yes. As the value would resolve to the default value from the expression which in turn would be set.